# I want to search and replace a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to search each record (records are defined by blank lines) in a file for the pattern `NAME#AAAA`. If it matches, then insert an `#` in front of the record's `age` and insert a line `age NIL` at the end of the record.

INPUT FILE:

```
NAME#AAAA
STD 1
SEC A
AGE 5

NAME#BBBB
STD 2
SEC B
AGE 6


NAME#CCCC
STD 3
SEC C
AGE 7

NAME#AAAA
STD 4
AGE 9


NAME#AAAA
STD 7
SEC A
AGE 12
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
NAME#AAAA
STD 1
SEC A
#AGE 5
AGE NIL

NAME#BBBB
STD 2
SEC B
AGE 6

NAME#CCCC
STD 3
SEC C
AGE 7


NAME#AAAA
STD 4
#AGE 9
AGE NIL


NAME#AAAA
STD 7
SEC A
#AGE 12
AGE NIL
```

Comment: Ok Fine.. now its clearly. Sorry once again.

Comment: No worries. We do things a little differently from similar sites, it takes some getting used to. You might want to take the [tour] or read the [help] to understand how the site works. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see records separated by blank lines ("paragraphs", if you like), Perl's "paragraph mode" is often a good solution:

```
$ perl -00lpe 'if(/NAME#AAAA/){s/\bAGE\s/#$&/; s/$/\nAGE NIL/;}' file
NAME#AAAA
STD 1
SEC A
#AGE 5
AGE NIL

NAME#BBBB
STD 2
SEC B
AGE 6

NAME#CCCC
STD 3
SEC C
AGE 7

NAME#AAAA
STD 4
#AGE 9
AGE NIL

NAME#AAAA
STD 7
SEC A
#AGE 12
AGE NIL
```

#### Explanation

- `-00` : this activates perl's paragraph mode, where each "paragraph" (group of non-blank lines until a blank one) is treated as a "line".
- `-l` : removes trailing newlines from each input record (each paragraph) and adds a newline to each `print` call.
  `-pe` : print each input record aftrer applying the script given by `-e` to it.

So, those flags make `perl` read over the input file, applying the script to each record, and then printing the result. The script itself does:

- `if(/NAME#AAAA/)` : if this record matches `NAME#AAAA`.
- `s/\bAGE\s/#$&/` : The `s/foo/bar/` is the substitution operator. It will replace `foo` with `bar`. Here, I am replacing `AGE` with itself preceded by a `#`. The `\b` matches word boundaries, and will exclude things like `ADAGE` from the match. The `$&` is a special variable and means "whatever was matched. So, `s/\bAGE\s/#$&/` will replace `AGE` with `#AGE`.
- `s/$/\nAGE NIL/` : The `$` matches the end of the record. So replacing it with something else will append to the end of the record. This command appends `AGE NIL` to the end of the matched record.

Note that all operations here are case sensitive. If you need case insensitive matching use this instead:

```
perl -00lpe 'if(/NAME#AAAA/i){s/\bAGE\s/#$&/i; s/$/\nAGE NIL/i;}' file
```

Comment: wow!!! That's great,.. Thank you so much :):):) i have one more scenario. Just like this.. shall i ask it here or open a new thread? in the same scenario, if i have to move the #AGE to the top of the paragraph and insert the new line just like this.  Also, i need the vice versa of it(to revert back the changes).

Comment: @user4432340 you're welcome :).  Please do take a moment to take the [tour] though, it only takes a minute and will explain how this site works. Yes, if you have a new question, post it separately. You can link back to this one for reference, if you need to. If this answer solved your issue, you can [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.